# Laravel - Convert table column value to slug

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, slug, accessor

I want to convert column value to slug with **`str_slug`** to use in where clause. I heard **Mutators** & **Accessors**, also I heard they can't be used to query table.

Here have converted name to slug in blade and I want to match **`name`** field to slug in controller

**Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'price'];
```

**Table**

```
| ID | name    | price
| 1  |  ST SD  | 7
| 2  |  CA WA  | 4
```

**Blade**

```
<a href="{{ route('buy', str_slug($item->name)]) }}">Buy Now</a>
```

**Controller**

```
public function buy($name){
  $item = Name::where('name' => $name)->first();
  }
```

**Here in controller, I want to convert the name field to slug to match slugged value of $item->name in blade**

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add a slug column in your table so you can ``Name::where('slug' => $slug)->first();``. I got a function ready that creates slugs for models and check if its unique to add an incremental to the end of the string

Comment: Agree with @Taacoo, you must create a separate column for `slug`, you can add unique constraint to it if you want. Then you can use Sahil Gupta answer to generate unique slug.

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answers?

Answer (score 0):

You've to add a unique number next to slugs.

```
public function createSlug($title)
{
    // Normalize the title
    $slug = str_slug($title);
    if (Name::where('name' => $slug)->count() <= 0){
        return $slug;
    }
    $i =1; 
    while (Name::where('name' => $slug)->count() > 0) {
        $slug = $slug.'-'.$i;
        if (Name::where('name' => $slug)->count() <= 0) {
            return $slug;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    throw new \Exception('Can not create a unique slug.');           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use for my slugs. Just place it in your model and call the function when when you are creating a new instance of the Model.

```
 public static function generateUniqueSlug($value){
    $temp = str_slug($value, '-');
    if(!Deck::all()->where('slug',$temp)->isEmpty()){
        $i = 1;
        $newslug = $temp . '-' . $i;
        while(!Deck::all()->where('slug',$newslug)->isEmpty()){
            $i++;
            $newslug = $temp . '-' . $i;
        }
        $temp =  $newslug;
    }
    return $temp;
}
```

Just use it like this:

```
$p = new Post();
$p->title = $request->title;
$p->slug = $p->genereateUniqueSlug($request->title);
$p->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my product model code with boot method. I have implemented it on my avored product model

[avored ecommerce product model file](http://%20ed%20e/blob/master/src/Mxodels/Database/Product.php)